# Record and save audio in c# .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, audio

Is there anyway that I can record sound from a microphone using c# .net

- What is the best option if i have to save the audio online in terms of the file occupying storage space.
- Any particular format that the file should be saved in for optimum output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use either a small flash application or a silverlight application to do the actual recording. Then you upload the file to your application using a web service or similar.

And mp3 is sort of a standard file format for sound on the web. So I'd go with that.

Comment: Silverlight do not have microphone support (unless it got implemented recently)

Comment: Since Silverlight for Windows Phone has microphone support. I just assumed that browser-silverlight had it to.

Comment: I think it has microphone support since Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these projects:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SoundRecord.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67568/Creating-a-Sound-Recorder-in-C-and-Csharp.aspx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cswavrec.aspx

What is the best option if i have to save the audio online in terms of the file occupying storage space.

- May be real media (.rm).

Any particular format that the file should be saved in for optimum output.

- Not sure but I think that depends on
  your player.

You might also be interested in [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for converting the media and its [c# wrapper library](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/).